# Encrypted protocol for controlling robot via internet?

Tags: network-protocols, robotics

I want to control motion of my robot via internet. I use "clien-server architecture": robot connects to server and user connects to server. I need network encrypted protocol that keeps connection alive. I need to send commands to robot in real time from user's machine. Server have to know if connection to robot was broken.
Software is written in C++. So I need C or C++ library that implements this protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a library specifically, but I would look into IM (instant messaging) libraries.  How cool would it be to send an IM to your robot to control it?!  I am vaguely aware that there are open source libraries that let you create your own IM server, or work with existing ones.